# Simple swig python example in VS2008 - import error - internal (py)readline error

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have recently been learning the very basics of swig with python and come across a strange error where importing the module when running python in a command windows returns this.

```
>>> import simpFunc
Readline internal error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\Python\winx64\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 671, in hook_wrapper_23
    res = ensure_str(readline_hook(prompt))
  File "D:\Dev\Python\winx64\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 342, in readline
    return self.mode.readline(prompt)
  File "D:\Dev\Python\winx64\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 116, in readline
    self._print_prompt()
  File "D:\Dev\Python\winx64\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 298, in _print_prompt
    n = c.write_scrolling(self.prompt, self.prompt_color)
  File "D:\Dev\Python\winx64\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 289, in write_scrolling
    w, h = self.size()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Although after this error it is possible to use the modules function correctly and when running it in a script there is no error at all.

i was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the matter. I am currently using Visual Studio 2008 x64 Command Prompt to build and link this. Python Version 2.7.2 , Swig Version 2.0.4

Its not just for this specific example either i have tried a couple of c examples which both have this error.

Below listed are the files i am using.

simpFunc.cpp

```
#include "simpFunc.h"

void printNum(int aNum) 
{
std::cout << "num is " << aNum << std::endl;
}
```

simpFunc.h

```
#include <iostream>

void printNum(int aNum);
```

simpFunc.i

```
/* File : simpFunc.i */
%module simpFunc
%{
#include "simpFunc.h"
%}
%include "simpFunc.h"
```

Below is the commands i use to create the .pyd

```
swig.exe -python -c++ simpFunc.i
cl /c simpFunc.cpp simpFunc_wrap.cxx /I"D:\Dev\Python\winx64\include"
link /dll /out:.\_simpFunc.pyd /LIBPATH:D:\Dev\Python\winx64\libs simpFunc.obj simpFunc_wrap.obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a known issue for this 
[issue8275](http://bugs.python.org/issue8275%20issue8275)

the source of the problem is 
After loading the dll, GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo always returns zero,
so size returns None and everybody is unhappy.

[source of the problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyreadline/+bug/806452)

The issue seems to be resolved if self.hout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) is called again in the beginning of the size function, just before calling GetConsoleScreenBufferinfo

use this 
[console.py](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/36058566/console.py)

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to track this down for a while now, ugh.